# Currency of in-app billing transaction

Tags: in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, currency

I see that the response I get from Google Play after the user had purchased one of my in-app products contains the following information:
Description, ItemType, Json, Price, Sku, Title and Type
Price is a string that contains the currency and price. eg: "€1.17".

I would like to get the same price information in a more structured way and separately. Something like a three digit ISO code of the currency and the price in numeric format, without having to parse the string, which would have been ugly and unsafe.

Do you think that there is a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check `price_amount_micros` field.

> Price in micro-units, where 1,000,000 micro-units equal one unit of
>   the currency. For example, if price is "€7.99", price_amount_micros is
>   "7990000".

More here: [In-app Billing Reference](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html)

Comment: Actually I might have confused you. All the details I wrote above are actually coming from the details of the product prior to payment. Thanks for the input. The property you said seems more appropriate. I will slightly change my question though. 

The purchase response does not contain any information about the amount the user was charged. Getting product details before or after the transaction is not very safe, as there is a slight possibility of change before or after the transaction. I was wondering if I can somehow query to get the currency and amount of the actual transaction!

Comment: @papadi The price amount doesn't change automatically. You have to change it manually via developer console. Once set it stays fixed no matter what's the current price of given currency. It's safe to use the amount recorded before/after transaction.